# System.FormatException: 'The input string does not have the correct format.'

Tags: c#, mysql

The query doesn't work

I want to modify the fields with a query ,the structure is difficult

```
     private void carregaDades()
                {
                    BaseDades bd = new BaseDades();
                    // recuperem llista de la BD
                    magatzem ma = new magatzem();

                    ma.recuperaDades();
                    String sql = "update Almacen set id_almacen=" + Convert.ToInt32(TB_ID.Text) + "'nom_almacen='" +
                     TB_NOM.Text + "',pais='" + TB_PAIS.Text + "',municipi='" + TB_MUNICIPI.Text + ";"; 
                    bd.ExecutaSql(sql, bd.getConnection());

                }




public MySqlDataAdapter recuperaDades()
        {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM  Almacen;";
            BaseDades BDAlmacen = new BaseDades();
            return BDAlmacen.consultaSELECT(sql, BDAlmacen.getConnection());
        }
```

Comment: don't use string concatenation. use a parameterized queries.

Comment: Print out the string `sql` and you will see the issue (there are two that I can see). If it's not obvious, paste it into a SQL prompt and run it to see the errors.

Answer (score -2):

Your single quotes do not look right, try this

```
            String sql = "update Almacen set id_almacen=" + Convert.ToInt32(TB_ID.Text) + ",nom_almacen='" +
             TB_NOM.Text + "',pais='" + TB_PAIS.Text + "',municipi='" + TB_MUNICIPI.Text + "';";
```

Comment: * but do not have enough information to know for sure* is a comment -- Not an answer.

Comment: Trying to get my reputation up so that I can comment lol, also updated my answer to help more